# Reviewing a question flagged as duplicate not showing duplicate tab

Tags: bug, review-queues, duplicate-questions

I've just come across the following question flagged as `duplicate` and `unclear what you're asking` in the close queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15738106

I'd expect to see the "duplicate" tab on the main review page to compare the two questions, however this doesn't appear. I assume this is because of the multiple flags on the question.

Is there a reason why this doesn't get displayed?

**What appears:**

> [image]

**What I'd expect to see:**

> [image]

Comment: I wonder if it was flagged as a dupe and since the system does not treate flags like votes it won't actually give you the dupe tab.

Answer (score -2):

I frequently find questions "flagged as duplicate" where there is no reference to the purported "duplicate" question.  Why is it possible to flag something as a duplicate without being forced to include a reference to the duplicate question?

Comment: I'm not at all sure how this answers the question... This feels more like a comment than an answer. In fact, you're really just asking a question, rather than answering one. (Here's the answer, though: You cannot flag or vote to close as duplicate without including a link to the other question. It _isn't_ possible. I'm not sure if you're seeing comments about the question being duplicate or what, but what you're suggesting can't happen.)